# Python GraphQL query issue

Tags: python, graphql

I'm using Python to make requests to Pipefy GraphQL API.
I already read the documentation and make search in pipefy forum, but
I could not figure what is wrong with the query bellow:

```py
pipeId = '171258'
query ="""
        {
            "query": "{allCards(pipeId: %s, first: 30, after: 'WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0'){pageInfo{endCursor hasNextPage}edges{node{id title}}}}"
        }
        """%(pipeid)
```

The query worked pretty well until I added the `after` parameter.
I already tried variations like:

`after: "WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0"`

`after: \"WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0\"`

`after: \n"WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0\n"`

I know the issue is related with the escaping, because the API return messages like this:

```py
'{"errors":[{"locations":[{"column":45,"line":1}],"message":"token recognition error at: \'\'\'"},{"locations":[{"column":77,"line":1}],"message":"token recognition error at: \'\'\'"}]}\n'
```

(this message is returned when the request is made with `after: 'WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0'`)

Any help here would be immensely handful! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you today (and saw your post on Pipefy's Support page). I personally entered in contact with Pipefy's developers but they weren't helpful at all.

I solved it by escaping the query correctly.

Try like this:

```
query = '{"query": "{ allCards(pipeId: %s, first: 30, after: \\"WyIxLjAiLCI1ODAuMCIsMzI0OTU0NF0\\"){ pageInfo{endCursor hasNextPage } edges { node { id title } } } }"}'
```

Using single quotes to define the string and double-backslashes before the doublequotes included in the cursor.

Comment: Sure! Don't forget to upvote-it and mark it as answer, to help other to find it :))

Answer (score 1):

With the code snippet below you are able to call the function `get_card_list` passing the authentication token (as String) and the pipe_id (as integer) and retrieve the whole card list of your pipe.

The `get_card_list` function will call the function `request_card_list` until the hasNextpage is set to False, updating the cursor in each call.

```
# Function responsible to get cards from a pipe using Pipefy's GraphQL API
def request_card_list(auth_token, pipe_id, hasNextPage=False, endCursor=""):    
    url = "https://api.pipefy.com/graphql"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' %auth_token
    }
    if not hasNextPage:
        payload = '{"query": "{ allCards(pipeId: %i, first: 50) { edges { node { id title  phases_history { phase { name } firstTimeIn lastTimeOut } } cursor } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }"}' %pipe_id
    else:
        payload = '{"query": "{ allCards(pipeId: %i, first: 50, after: \\"%s\\") { edges { node { id title  phases_history { phase { name } firstTimeIn lastTimeOut } } cursor } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } }"}' % (pipe_id, endCursor)

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response_body = response.text
    response_body_dict = json.loads(response_body)
    response_dict_list = response_body_dict['data']['allCards']['edges']

    card_list = []
    for d in response_dict_list:
        for h in d['node']['phases_history']:
            h['firstTimeIn'] = datetime.strptime(h['firstTimeIn'], date_format)
            if h['lastTimeOut']:
                h['lastTimeOut'] = datetime.strptime(h['lastTimeOut'], date_format)
        card_list.append(d['node'])

    return_list = [card_list, response_body_dict['data']['allCards']['pageInfo']['hasNextPage'], response_body_dict['data']['allCards']['pageInfo']['endCursor']]
    return return_list

# Function responsible to get all cards from a pipe using Pipefy's GraphQL API and pagination
def get_card_list(auth_token, pipe_id):
    card_list = []
    response = request_card_list(auth_token, pipe_id)
    card_list = card_list + response[0]

    while response[1]:
        response = request_card_list(auth_token, pipe_id, response[1], response[2])
        card_list = card_list + response[0]

    return(card_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Lodi answer, I was able to do the next step.
How to use a variable to pass the "after" parameter for the query
As it was quite difficult I decide to share it here for those facing the same challenge.

```
end_cursor = 'WyIxLjAiLCI2NTcuMCIsNDgwNDA2OV0'
end_cursor = "\\" + "\"" + end_cursor  + "\\" + "\""
# desired output: end_cursor = '\"WyIxLjAiLCI2NTcuMCIsNDgwNDA2OV0\"'
query ="""
       {
        "query": "{allCards(pipeId: %s, first: 50, after: %s){pageInfo{endCursor hasNextPage}edges{node{id title}}}}"
        }
       """%(pipeid, end_cursor)
```

Comment: Sir, the correct way to continue getting help would be to create a new question. But, as I already have it solved in a code snippet, I will post as answer below.

Comment: Thanks Lodi, You helped me a lot!